# How to call a function in controller from view for input type = number

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3

I have a submit button for input type = "number", when I change value of input tag, `subtotal` will be change:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('cart/update') ?>" method="post">
    <input type="number" name="qty_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['qty']; ?>"/>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
    Total: <?php echo number_format($row['subtotal']); ?>
</form>
```

In `Cart` controller, this function update `qty` and change value of `$row['subtotal']`:

```
 function update(){
    $carts = $this->cart->contents();
    foreach ($carts as $key => $row){
        $total_qty = $this->input->post('qty_'.$row['id']);
        $data = array();
        $data['rowid'] = $key;
        $data['qty'] = $total_qty;
        $this->cart->update($data);
    }
    redirect(base_url('cart'));
}
```

Then, I want to use a onchange event, but I dont have idea. How to call update function? 
I try this:

```
<input type="number" name="qty_<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $row['qty']; ?>" onchange=<?php echo base_url('cart/update')?>/>
```

Of course, it doesn't work.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: use ajax or `onchange="this.form.submit()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onchange` attribute executes javascript, so you can't just provide it a URL. You should be able to submit the form via: `onchange="this.form.submit()"`